# How can I convert string from database e.g RaceTime and I call it as from query sum(RaceTime) and I want to convert it to timeformat?

Tags: java

I want to convert string from database table e.g `RaceTime` and call
   it on query as `SUM(RaceTime) as AVG FROM registrationevent`. I want to 
   format the result as TimeFormat the result I get as string is
   31954053 I want to convert it time e.g    23:12:12 and later I will
   get the AVG"

```
try {
    String sql = "SELECT SUM(RaceTime) as AVG FROM registrationevent;";
    ps=con.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs=ps.executeQuery();
    rs.next();
    String avgs = rs.getString("AVG");  
    avg.setText(avgs);
}
catch (Exception e) 
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you actually asking about. What is `RaceTime` column datatype?

Comment: which DB are you using ?

Comment: How do you convert `31954053` to `23:12:12`?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `SEC_TO_TIME()` to convert seconds to time format if that's what you want.

```
select SEC_TO_TIME(31954053);
```

will give you `838:59:59` in `hh:mm:ss` format.

Comment: how do you know that `SEC_TO_TIME()` is available in the DB OP is using?

Comment: I thought it's MySQL. I'll wait till OP responds.

Comment: Why did you think it was MySQL? There is nothing in the question to suggest that. Besides, interpreting the value as seconds does not yield the value OP seeks. This answer does not go close to answering the question.

Comment: Can you wait till OP responds before calling it all wrong?